# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: When I run docker

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a chat application so I need to use both gunicorn and uvicorn in order to have websockets working.
When I build the image only for the wsgi with gunicorn it's working and when I add the uvicorn for handling asgi I run into this error

asgi.py

```
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from chat import urls
import os
import django


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_CONFIGURATION", "Local")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "friendly_enigma.settings")
django.setup()


application = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": application,
        "websocket": URLRouter(websocket_urls.websocket_urlpatterns)
    }
)
```

dockerfile command

```
CMD gunicorn friendly_enigma.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 & gunicorn friendly_enigma.routing:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind=0.0.0.0:8001
```

logs

```
[2022-10-20 14:10:31 +0000] [7] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-10-20 14:10:31 +0000] [7] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (7)
[2022-10-20 14:10:31 +0000] [7] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-10-20 14:10:31 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2022-10-20 14:10:31 +0000] [8] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-10-20 14:10:31 +0000] [8] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8001 (8)
[2022-10-20 14:10:31 +0000] [8] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[2022-10-20 14:10:31 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
[2022-10-20 14:10:32 +0000] [12] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/workers.py", line 66, in init_process
    super(UvicornWorker, self).init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/code/friendly_enigma/routing.py", line 14, in <module>
    from chat import websocket_urls
  File "/code/chat/websocket_urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import consumers
  File "/code/chat/consumers.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import Message, Dialog, UserModel
  File "/code/chat/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from model_utils.models import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/model_utils/models.py", line 19, in <module>
    class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
[2022-10-20 14:10:32 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
[2022-10-20 14:10:32 +0000] [8] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2022-10-20 14:10:32 +0000] [8] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I did the research but couldn't quit find what could be the problem in my case.

Is there anything else I need to share?